# File format conversion library

Tags: java, html, file-format

Are there any well known solutions that meet/exceed below requirements?

- conversion from multiple non-graphical document formats to and from HTML (e.g. doc<->HTML, pdf<->html, odt<->html, etc.)
- command line or API (Java API is preferable)
- cross-platform
- commercial or open source

Comment: Are you sure you need pdf -> html(or any other format). I don't think there is any library available for that. For pdf, it would be one way, as far as I know.

Comment: In fact, it's possible with some limitations. Take a look at this: http://www.google.com/search?q=pdf2html

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice has a rich API that supports conversion between the various supported formats. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156915/good-way-to-create-pdf-from-office-documents-in-java) question. It recommends using [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter).

Answer (score 0):

With [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/whatis) you can export to various output formats, but reverting is always hard. For pdf you can try [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/)

Answer (score 0):

I (having written an all in one Tex/LaTeX -> HTML and ASCII text and RTF convertor),
would say this would be quite an undertaking.

The problem with this, is these various 'document' formats are intended for rather different purposes.
And while there are indeed such conversion tools between some of these formats,
there is often a conceptual disparity in the structure, meaning and implementation of 'document'
and it is very often is necessary to trade off on features supported by one format to hack together
an acceptable output in another.
For example, PDF is very strong in presentation, precise positioning and support for fonts, where
as HTML is more concerned about structure with practically no considuration for these things
(without CSS).

I am curious how do you envision such an API being used, 
when usually someone simply wants a conversion program?